# Implementing OAUth in Marklogic

Tags: azure, oauth, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-9

I have an Marklogic application which is to be protected by Azure AD
oauth .Flow is like ,there is an angular frontend from which a authorization token is passed to backend (Marklogic app).Requirement is to protect the backend by validating the token .I dont find any supporting libraries in Marklogic or Xquery .I am thinking to call any Java Api's from Marklogic if it works .Any help is appreciated .